# How can I call a function that requires a return value that calls WebClient?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Here is the function I have now that obviously doesn't work. The reason it doesn't work is because WebClient is asynchronous and `data` is empty before it gets filled by WebClient and crashes on the XML reader. How can I call WebClient within this function and still allow it to return `ServerResult` as required with or without needing an external event handler?

```
static public ServerResult isBarcodeCorrectOnServer(string barcode)
{
            Dictionary<string, IPropertyListItem> dict = configDictionary();

            string urlString = (string.Format("http://www.myurl.com/app/getbarcodetype.php?realbarcode={0}&type={1}", barcode, dict["type"]));

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string data = "";
            wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error == null)
                {
                    //Process the result...
                    data = e.Result;
                }
            };
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(urlString));

            StringReader stream = new StringReader(data);
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            var document = XDocument.Load(reader);
            var username = document.Descendants("item");
            var theDict = username.Elements().ToDictionary(ev => ev.Name.LocalName, ev => ev.Value);

            if (theDict.ContainsKey("type") == true && theDict["type"].ToString() == dict["type"].ToString())
            {
                return ServerResult.kOnServer;
            }
            else if (theDict.ContainsKey("type") == true)
            {
                return ServerResult.kWrongType;
            }
            else
            {
                return ServerResult.kNotOnServer;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use non-async version of DownloadString?

Comment: Silverlight does not support non-async

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't without "hacks" and you shouldn't - embrace asynchrony and pass in a delegate that you want to be executed once the download is completed:

```
static public void isBarcodeCorrectOnServer(string barcode, Action<string> completed)
{
    //..
    wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
       if (e.Error == null)
       {
            //Process the result...
            data = e.Result;
            completed(data);
       }
    };
    //..
}
```

You can move all your processing code now into a separate method which you call with the download result.

Comment: Passing in the delegate is what I needed to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't, basically. Or at the very least you shouldn't. You've got a method which is designed to be *synchronous*, on a platform which is designed for *asynchronous* IO.

Fundamentally, you should design your code to work with the platform. Accept that it *will* be asynchronous, and make the calling code deal with that.

Note that when C# 5 comes out and when it's supported by Windows Phone, all of this will be a *lot* simpler using `async`. You'd return a `Task<ServerResult>` from the method, and `await` the result of the `WebClient`. If you're only developing for fun (so don't mind working with a CTP which has some bugs, and may not be valid to ship for marketplace apps) you can [do that today](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360).